# How to controll hovertemplate when using `text` as argument

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have a surface I want to display with `plotly` (it has to be a surface and not a 3D mesh because a 3D mesh [is not appropiate](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2194) so I *must* pass on a matrix not a data.frame).

For this I want to control the hoverinfo so it won't display the `x, y, z` coordinated but it does display `x * y = ...` and `x + y = ...`.  However I am encountering a problem with the `hovertext` argument. Which correctly displays the things I want but also displays the `x, y, z` coordinates. Also, I can't get `"<extra></extra>"` to work.

This is attempt so far:

```
library(plotly)

mat <- 0:10 %*% t(0:10)

plot_ly() |>
  
  add_surface(z = ~mat,
              
              hovertext = paste(
                "X*Y:", mat, 
                "<br>X+Y: ", rep(0:10, each = 11) + rep(0:10, 11),
                "<extra></extra>") |>
                matrix(ncol = 11),
              
              hovertemplate = text)
```

I would like to know:

- How can I remove the `x, y, z` coordinates from the `hovertemplate`?
- How can I use `"<extra></extra>"` argument when using `hovertemplate = text`?

EDIT: Following @Kat's comment I edited this post to reflect what I learned. Thanks Kat!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Everything in the tooltip is text, so you wouldn't be able to calculate values within `hovertemplate`. Instead of using `text`, use `hovertext`.

Comment: @Kat thanks! I updated the question following your comments. The problem now is that there is no way to use `"<extra></extra>"` and I cant control whether or not the `x, y, z` coordinates appear.

Comment: Ah, but you can...`hovertemplate = "X: %{x}<br>Y: %{y}<br>Z: %{z}<br>Whatever: %{hovertext}<extra></extra>"`

Comment: @Kat, you Sir/Madam/Non-binary individual are very kind! thank you for your help! TBH I don't understand why `%{text}` or `%{hovertext}` work sometimes but not others. But you have solved the issue andI'll be happy to mark your response as an answer if you post it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `text`, use `hovertext`.

```
library(plotly)

mat <- 0:10 %*% t(0:10)

plot_ly() |>
  add_surface(z = ~mat,               
              hovertext = mat,  # hovertext to use in the template
              hovertemplate = paste0("X: %{x}<br>Y: %{y}<br>",
                                     "Z: %{z}<br>Whatever: %{hovertext}",
                                     "<extra></extra>"))
```